# Поиск Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть карточка магазина с сектором A71(А - в русской раскладке), если ввести в поле поиска A71  с буквой А в английской раскладке поиск не удается, как сделать чтобы поиск работал вне зависимости от того в какой раскладке буквы (или языки - русский/аглийский)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте посмотреть на странице [плагины для поиска](https://wpcafe.org/tutorials/uluchshaem-poisk-po-wordpress-saytu-7-besplatnyih-plaginov/)

Некоторые из них поддерживают совпадение части слова, так что если буква не совпадет, то все равно в результат поиска должно попасть

Comment: C плагинами не получилось, пришлось в карточках магазинов указывать метки c русской раскладкой. Долго, нудно, но работает.